# Как запустить несколько postgresql CУБД, на разных контейнерах в одном хосте, через docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Я хочу запускать несколько баз postgresql на разных контейнерах одновременно.

У меня есть вот такой файл для **docker-compose**.

**- 1-й контейнер**

```bsh
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: booking_air_example
    image: postgres:11.7
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-root}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
      - //docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

**- 2-й контейнер**

```bsh
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: booking_air_2
    image: postgres:11.7
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-root}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
      - //docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

Я указал 2 разных имени контейнера, также у них входной порт со стороны хостовой системы - разный.

pgadmin - хотел бы, чтобы он работал с несколькими контейнерами.

Хотелось бы. чтобы контейнеры использовали одну заданную сеть (**postgres**).

Но когда я запуская 1-файл создается контейнер.

Когда запускаю 2 раз, он перезаписывает первый контейнер.

Как я понимаю, должны различаться имена объявляемых сервисов,  но почему, разве недостаточно объявить другое имя контейнера ?
Также нужно другой **volume** ?

Прошу укажите на ошибку и просьба пояснить что я делаю не так.

Comment: services:
  postgres: и services:
  postgres2: - вроде должно сработать, дело в имени сервиса

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения docker-compose вы, меняя название контейнера, говорите ему - поменяй в сервисе с именем postgres имя контейнера, но вы не говорите  сделай новый сервис с новыми параметрами.

Теперь к проблеме, как бы на вашем месте поступил бы я.
Я бы очевидно описал бы все в одном файле.

Как именно - я бы вынес ваши разнящиеся данные в переменные окружения, сделал бы .env-1 .env-2 файлы и подключал бы их через ключ (естественно в docker-compose файле не забыть сделать соответствующие изменения)

```
--env-file PATH             Specify an alternate environment file
```

И теперь самое важно и самое простое - как запустить один и тот же описанный сервис с разные данными ?

```
  -p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name
```

т.е. при запуске вы указываете разные имена через данный ключ и по сути таким образом получаете столько нужных сервисов с нужными параметрами сколько вам нужно, не плодя бесконечное количество файлов описания сервисов.

Comment: дело в том, что я запускаю docker-compose из среды разработоки Intellij idea. И для каждого проекта, настроен свой docker-compose.  Я поменял название сервисов и они отличаются в каждом файле, но при запуске получаю предупреждение , я нашел информацию  об этом, и сказано, что нужно запускать эти сервисы в разных проектах. Но так и не смог разобраться. как в этом случае должны выглядеть мои файлы docker-compose

Comment: Не вижу причин почему бы в IDE не сделать то о чем я написал. В настройках сервиса вы можете добавлять любые нужные вам параметры, в том числе подставлять нужные вам файлы с переменными окружения. Ну или в данном случае вы попросту в каждом проекте называете сервисы по-разному, вот и всё.

Comment: Действительно поднимается второй контейнер, только вот коннект к нему не проходит.

Answer (score 0):

А что вам мешает в одном docker-compose поднять два контейнера Postgresql?
Примерно так:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: booking_air_example
    image: postgres:11.7
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-root}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
      - //docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  postgres1:
    container_name: booking_air_2
    image: postgres:11.7
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-root}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
      - //docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - postgres1
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  postgres1:
  pgadmin:
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы так связать в общую сеть два контейнера (когда последовательно разные `compose`-файлы запускаешь), нужно внизу второго контейнера указать:

```
networks:
    network_name: имя_сети
        external: true
        driver: bridge
```

только здесь имя сети будет не таким, как в первом сервисе, а какой-нибудь `postgres_postgres` (в вашем случае) - это зависит от имени сети и имени сервиса, посмотреть названия существующих сетей можно командой `docker network ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Перетирают друг друга из-за того что пишут данные в один том.

```
   volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
```

Чтоб они были одной сети - непонятно зачем... ведь порт проброшен на хоста!
Но можно. Создайте новую глобальную подсеть докера

```
docker network create -d bridge my-pgs
```

И в композе как

```
networks:
    my-pgs:
        name: my-pgs
        external: true
        driver: bridge
```